# Integer class does not behave as reference type

Tags: java, reference, integer, wrapper

Integer doesn't behave as a Reference Type. For example code below produces unexpected result

```
    class Playground {
            public static void main(String[ ] args) {
                Integer i = 10;
                Integer num = i;
                i--;
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
                System.out.println("num = " + num);
            }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
i = 9
num = 10
```

I have expected "num" to be 9 as well cause Integer "num" references  Integer "i". The substractaction happens here from the same object num is referencing, but looks like "-" operator is overriding some behaviour and creates an new Integer object. What exactly is happening here? And what other classes behave like that?

Comment: What output would you have expected if you had written `i = i - 1;` instead of `i--;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer` objects are immutable.

After `Integer num = i;` the local variable `num` references the same `Integer` object as `i` - specifically an `Integer` object that contains the value 10.

But when you write `i--;` then `i` can no longer reference the same `Integer` object as `num` - the local variable `i` gets assigned with a reference to an `Integer` object that contains the value 9.

Since `num` was not assigned to it still references the `Integer` object with the value 10.